# Solver.xlam add in missing in mac 2011 excel version 14.0.0

Tags: excel

When i click tools -> addin , i dnt find solver.xlam to add
macbook 2011, excel version 14.0.0

Should i update my excel?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQtZB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the original install did not include it.

Re-instal Excel this time making sure the add-ins are included.

Then you will see them in that box.

Usually done by rushed IT depts to save a few seconds...

Comment: Thank you,will do that and check